# Python string sequcence like excel

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want sequence like excel headers.

e.g :
**A,B,C,..,Z,AA,AB....**

My code

```
>>> s = 'A'
>>> chr(ord(s) + 1)
'B'
>>> s = 'Z'
>>> chr(ord(s) + 1)  
'['
>>> 
# I want AA after chr(ord('Z') + 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trying this:

```
def get_colnum_string(n):
    string = ""
    while n > 0:
        n, remainder = divmod(n - 1, 26)
        string = chr(65 + remainder) + string
    return string
```

```
>>> get_colnum_string(1)
'A'
>>> get_colnum_string(26)
'Z'
>>> get_colnum_string(27)
'AA'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

using itertools,

```
import itertools

alpha = [chr(x) for x in range(65, 91)] # create a list of character's

print(alpha + [k + v for k,v in itertools.product(alpha, repeat=2)])
```

Comment: you can also use `string.ascii_uppercase` instead of `alpha`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to go "`n` deep", meaning that you want your last header to have `n` letters:

```
import itertools
import string


def generateHeaders(n=None):
    if n is None: nums = itertools.count(1)
    else: nums = range(1, n+1)

    for n in nums:
        yield from map(''.join, itertools.product(*([string.ascii_uppercase]*n)))
```

Output testing:

```
for _,header in zip(range(60), generateHeaders()): print(header)


A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
AA
AB
AC
AD
AE
AF
AG
AH
AI
AJ
AK
AL
AM
AN
AO
AP
AQ
AR
AS
AT
AU
AV
AW
AX
AY
AZ
BA
BB
BC
BD
BE
BF
BG
BH
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplely you may create a list to contain the sequance.
It's simple but not good enough.
e.g.

```py
seq = ['A', 'B', ... 'ZZ']
s = 'A'  # s.toupper() if required.
idx = seq.index(s)
if idx < 0:
  print('not in sequence')
  return   # or exit
next = idx + 1
if next >= len(seq):
  next = 0
print(seq[next])
```